# javascript(jquery-rails) not working fully in rails 3.1.rc5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

every time i use the remove method when deleting object via javascripts it does not work.

my destroy.js code is as follows.

```
$("#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>").remove();
    $('#comment-count-<%= @parent.id %>').html("<%= pluralize(@parent.comments.count,'comment')%>");
```

the pluralize works just fine

my _comment.html.erb is as follows

```
    <%= div_for comment do %>
<% if comment.user.profile.icon.exists? %>
     <%= image_tag comment.user.profile.icon.url(:small), :alt => comment.user.name, :class => "avatar tip", :title => comment.user.name %>
   <% else %>
   <%= image_tag comment.user.gender == 'Female' ? 'missing_woman.png' : 'missing_thumb.png', :alt => comment.user.name, :class => "avatar tip", :title => comment.user.name %>
   <% end %>
  <div class="comment-container">
     <span><%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user.profile, :class => "profile-link-small" %></span> <%= comment.comment%>
   <div><span style="color:#888;"><%= formatted_time(comment.created_at) %></span> &ndash;&ndash; <span class="rank"><%= comment.user.level %></span>
    <% if can? :update, comment%> |
<span class="del"><%= link_to "Delete", comment, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this comment?", :method => :delete, :remote => true %></span>
  <% else %>
        <span class="dialog_link">Delete</span>
  <% end %>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
<% end %>
```

It use to work before but after i updated to rails rc5 it storped

Comment: just modified the code it not a typo

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: this is what i see in my javascript console `$("#new_comment").remove();
$('#comment-count-3').html("1 comment");`

Comment: it does not show that it is removing the comment

Comment: @mu is too short. yes i have checked as you instructed and every thing works fine but why did you have to remove your answer it is a very good one and it helped me a lot. Thanks man. Its like the problem is from rc5 it does not pass the `dom_id` to the html attribute becacus what i did works fine in rc4 and below but does not work in rc5. I had to use you description to pass it manull like this `$("#comment-<%= @comment.id %>").remove();` and gave my erb this `<li class="comment" id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">` thanks for your help

Comment: I deleted my old answer because I didn't think was addressing your real problem. I can undelete it if you want it around or if you think it might be useful to someone. So the real problem was with `dom_id` and you have everything working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery says this:

```
$("#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>").remove();
//-------------^
```

But your ERB says this:

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
```

Your [`div_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for) should produce HTML something like this:

```
<div id="comment_11">
    <!-- ... -->
<div>
```

Assuming that `comment` is a Comment object with id 11. Then [`dom_id`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id) on the same comment would produce `comment_11` and that's all good.

However, you're using `@comment` (an instance variable) to generate the DOM ID for the jQuery [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove) call but the local variable `comment` for the HTML. I'd guess that `comment` is the right one and you're feeding a `nil` to `dom_id`, the result is that the IDs don't match and your jQuery does nothing useful.

Comment: pls what do you suggest. This has worked for me before updating my rails gem

Comment: Uchenna Okafor found this useful for other things so I resurrected it. The real problem is somewhere else (see comments on the question).