# Rails - handling an Ajax destroy call on a polymorphic association

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to destroy a comment through Ajax.  In my app, my comment model uses a polymorphic association. The comment deletes successfully (in the database) using the code below.  However, when I call the destroy.js.erb, it doesn't do anything and I think the problem is that the dom_id doesn't match the HTML id, so it is not updating. I think I am experiencing the same thing that @mu_is_too_short articulated in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965321/1276696). I need help with how to solve this though. I do not know if the solution involves a) somehow passing the local variable comment to the destory.js.erb or b) another solution.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :feeds do
  resources :comments
end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
 $('#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>')
   .fadeOut ->
   $(this).remove()
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
 <div id=<%= dom_id(comment) %> class="comment">
   <em>on <%= comment.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p') %></em>
   <%= link_to "Remove", [@commentable, comment], :method => :delete, :remote => true %>
   <%= simple_format comment.content %>
 </div>
```

**feeds/show.html.erb**

```
 <div id="comments">
    <%= render @comments %>
 </div>
```

**Comments controller**

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController

   def create
     @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
     if @comment.save
        respond_to do |format|
           format.html { redirect_to @commentable }
           format.js
        end
     else
        render :new
     end
    end

    def destroy
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      @commentable = @comment.commentable
        if @comment.destroy
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @commentable }
            format.js
          end
        end
     end
  end
```

**Feeds controller**

```
 class FeedsController < ApplicationController
  def show
     @feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
     @commentable = @feed
     @comments = @commentable.comments
     @comment = Comment.new
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, @comment will contain a comment when you get to destroy.js.erb, as you set it in the controller immediately before that, so I do not think it has anything to do with the referenced answer. I wonder if this is being caused by the lack of quotes around your id here: `<div id=<%= dom_id(comment) %> class="comment">`... I suspect if you correct this, and any other relevant HTML validation errors, it will start working.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was one problem. Also I realized I was mixing coffee script in an erb file. Once I cleaned up those two issues it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @diasks2 can you help me out please :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048284/ajax-with-polymorphic-association-destroy