# Ajax with Polymorphic Association (Destroy & Create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery, polymorphic-associations

**I have a polymorphic association with dailyposts & comments in my rails app**

Everything works fine in the database, but when I try to add Ajax to the Destroy Action (I used this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)
....it doesn't  work unless I refresh the page. (but my alert works in destroy.js.erb)

**I know my error is in destroy.js.erb**

New to Rails...Please help :)

*This is my code...*

**ROUTES**

```
resources :dailyposts do
  resources :comments
end
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
##Dailyposts

class DailypostsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @dailypost = Dailypost.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @commentable = @dailypost
    @comments = @commentable.comments.arrange(:order => :created_at)
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
end

##Comments

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_commentable

  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.create(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable }
        format.js
      end
    else
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment can't be blank."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @comment.commentable
    if @comment.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @commentable }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private 

  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

end
```

**VIEWS**

### Dailypost show.html.erb

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">

      <div>
        <%= raw(dailypost_with_links(@dailypost)) %>
      </div>

      <%= render "comments/form" %>

      <div id="comments">         
        <%= nested_comments @comments %>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

### _comment.html.erb

```
<section class="comments">
  <div class ="user">
    <%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user  %> 
    <%= comment.content %>
  </div>

##Here I am passing remote: true for ajax

    <% if current_user?(comment.user) %> 
      <%= link_to content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-trash icons"), [@commentable, comment], method: :delete,
                       data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
                       title: "Delete", remote: true %> |
    <% end %>

</section>
```

### destroy.js.erb

```
##alert is working
alert('ajax works!');

$('#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>').remove();
```

**LOGS**

```
Started DELETE "/dailyposts/11/comments/133" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-04 23:06:31 -0700
Processing by CommentsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"dailypost_id"=>"11", "id"=>"133"}
  Dailypost Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "dailyposts".* FROM "dailyposts" WHERE "dailyposts"."id" = ? ORDER BY dailyposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "11"]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'sgFH2XeZWEXCcjxiAwgfXg' LIMIT 1
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "133"]]
  Dailypost Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "dailyposts".* FROM "dailyposts" WHERE "dailyposts"."id" = 11 ORDER BY dailyposts.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE (comments.ancestry like '133/%' or comments.ancestry = '133')
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ?  [["id", 133]]
   (2.3ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered comments/destroy.js.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 10.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
```

Comment: Please provide information from the logs in order for us to be able to debug this question. The logs should contain some request information which might enable us to debug what's breaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Dailypost show.html.erb**

```
 <div id="comments">
   <%= render @comments %>
 </div>
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
 <div id="<%= dom_id(comment) %>"> 
   <%= comment.content %>
 </div>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
 $('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment))%>').appendTo('#comments').hide().fadeIn();
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
 $('#<%= dom_id(@comment) %>').remove();
```

Comment: No problem, I think one of the issues was having a div outside of the comment partial you are rendering that you can append to (i.e. the div with the id="comments").

Answer (score 1):

The redirect is breaking the response. Try changing it to `redirect_to( :back ) unless request.xhr?`

Comment: Right, but you did not implement the solution in your adjustment. The redirect is still breaking the response, look at the logs. Just qualify the redirect with `unless request.xhr?` (or wrap it in a format html block), to prevent the redirect. The redirect makes the ajax not happen.

Comment: i have updated the comment controller with unless request and these are the new logs i got.....it still doesnt work. :/

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like it is rendering the js, now, at least... `Rendered comments/destroy.js.erb (0.7ms)` Maybe you can throw an alert in there, on the first line, to verify it is being processed correctly. I suspect that the id being targeted is incorrect, but that part of the code is cut off in the view, so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: okay...i have modified the view. I dont think I am targeting an ID...how would i do that?

Comment: You are targeting an id in `destroy.js.erb`, where you `$('#edit_comment_<%= @comment.id %>').remove();`. Whatever you have there will be performed as js on the page. There probably just isn't an id of edit_comment_1 (or whatever), maybe it's just comment_1 (or whatever). If you have firebug installed, it will show you any relevant js errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `destroy.js.erb` , the second line does not work because there is no id like **edit_comment_1** of the format edit_comment_(:id).

In your `_comment.html.erb`, add an appropriate div with id that is used in your `.js.erb`

```
<section class="comment">

 <div id="edit_comment_<%= comment.id %>">

  <div class ="user">
     <%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user  %> 
     <%= comment.content %>
   </div>

    <% if current_user?(comment.user) %> 
      <%= link_to content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-trash icons"), [@commentable, comment], method: :delete,
                       data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" },
                       title: "Delete", remote: true %> |
    <% end %>

 </div>
</section>
```